# How to populate columns of a dataframe using a subset of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': list('AAABBCCAAC'),
    'prop1': list('xyzuuyxzzz'),
    'prop2': list('mnbnbbnnnn')
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': list('ABBCAA'),
    'prop1': [np.nan] * 6,
    'prop2': [np.nan] * 6,
    'keep_me': ['stuff'] * 6
})

  key prop1 prop2
0   A     x     m
1   A     y     n
2   A     z     b
3   B     u     n
4   B     u     b
5   C     y     b
6   C     x     n
7   A     z     n
8   A     z     n
9   C     z     n

  key  prop1  prop2 keep_me
0   A    NaN    NaN   stuff
1   B    NaN    NaN   stuff
2   B    NaN    NaN   stuff
3   C    NaN    NaN   stuff
4   A    NaN    NaN   stuff
5   A    NaN    NaN   stuff
```

I now want to populate columns `prop1` and `prop2` in `df2` using the values of `df1`. For each key, we will have more or equal rows in `df1` than in `df2` (in the example above: 5 times `A` vs 3 times `A`, 2 times `B` vs 2 times `B` and 3 times `C` vs 1 time `C`). For each key, I want to fill `df2` using the first `n` rows per key from `df1`.

So, my expected outcome for `df2` would be:

```
  key prop1 prop2 keep_me
0   A     x     m   stuff
1   B     u     n   stuff
2   B     u     b   stuff
3   C     y     b   stuff
4   A     y     n   stuff
5   A     z     b   stuff
```

As `key` is not unique, I cannot simple build a dictionary and then use `.map`.

I was hoping that something along these lines would work:

```
pd.concat([df2.set_index('key'), df1.set_index('key')], axis=1, join='inner')
```

but that fails with

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 22), indices imply (5, 10)

as - I guess - the index contains non-unique values.

How can I get my desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because duplicates in `key` values possible solution is create new counter columns in both `DataFrame`s by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), so possible replace missing values from `df2` with align by `MultiIndex` created by `key` and `g` columns with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('key').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('key').cumcount()

print (df1)
  key prop1 prop2  g
0   A     x     m  0
1   A     y     n  1
2   A     z     b  2
3   B     u     n  0
4   B     u     b  1
5   C     y     b  0
6   C     x     n  1
7   A     z     n  3
8   A     z     n  4
9   C     z     n  2

print (df2)
  key  prop1  prop2 keep_me  g
0   A    NaN    NaN   stuff  0
1   B    NaN    NaN   stuff  0
2   B    NaN    NaN   stuff  1
3   C    NaN    NaN   stuff  0
4   A    NaN    NaN   stuff  1
5   A    NaN    NaN   stuff  2
```

---

```
df = (df2.set_index(['key','g'])
        .fillna(df1.set_index(['key','g']))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
  key prop1 prop2 keep_me
0   A     x     m   stuff
1   B     u     n   stuff
2   B     u     b   stuff
3   C     y     b   stuff
4   A     y     n   stuff
5   A     z     b   stuff
```

Comment: Are you kidding me?!!!! by the time we can think of the logic, you have the answer. it is really not fair :-)

Comment: @SH-SF - hmmm, this is complicated, but I worked some time ago with something similar, so try fillna and I hope working nice for OP.

Comment: Seems to work fine, thanks (upvoted)! Will go through the solution and then accept later on (if nothing else pops up).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to build a dict first from df1 and then pop the elements to fill the NAs in df2

```
d = df1.groupby(by='key').apply(lambda x: x.values.tolist()).to_dict()
df2[['key','prop1','prop2']] = pd.DataFrame(df2.key.apply(lambda x: d[x].pop(0)).tolist())

    key prop1   prop2   keep_me
0   A   x       m       stuff
1   B   u       n       stuff
2   B   u       b       stuff
3   C   y       b       stuff
4   A   y       n       stuff
5   A   z       b       stuff
```